# Kodi (Music centric) remote control app

Tags: android, music

I have OpenElec installed on my Raspberry, and happily using [Kore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.syncedsynapse.kore2&hl=en) & [Yatse](http://yatse.tv/redmine/projects/yatse) as a remote control. Although I have a super large music collection and wish there was something available which was more music centric like iTunes. Supporting column filtering, ratings, and playlists.

[image: Column filtering]

Does something like this exist?